# Extending scalars from $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ to $\mathbb{Q}[G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group.

Let $M$ and $N$ be finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-modules such that $M$ is free as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Suppose that $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M$ and $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}N$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}[G]$-modules.

I want to show that there exists a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-homomorphism $\phi:N \to M$ such that the map
$$\mathrm{id}_\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\phi: \;\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}N \to \mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}M$$
is an **isomorphism** of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$-modules.

Any hints very gratefully received! I'm sure I must be missing something simple!

Comment: Thanks, but I'll press you to include the phrase "group ring" at least once in the body of the Question.

Comment: I'm not sure there is much value in that as it is completely clear from the notation

Comment: Doesn't it simply follow from the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups ? Write $N= Tor(N) \oplus \mathbb{Z}^r$, $M= \mathbb{Z}^r$. Up to a scalar, we may assume that the iso $\mathbb{Q}\otimes N\to \mathbb{Q}\otimes M$ sends the standard basis to integer valued vectors, and then define $N\to M$ by first projecting onto $\mathbb{Z}^r$ and then composing with aforementioned iso ? You can make the projection $G$-equivariant with the right action on $\mathbb{Z}^r$ (I think looking at the details there shows why you can't expect to have $M\to N$ )

Comment: @Max That's a neat approach!  I guess the question is whether we're allowed to assume the structure theorem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : it's true that some people don't want to use it but usually when you're talking about extension of scalars and group rings then you can safely assume the structure theorem

Comment: @Max fair enough. I think you should write that up as an answer, then.

Comment: @Max you can't make the decomposition of N into Tor(N) plus a free bit G-equivariant but it doesn't matter. Just replace N by N/Tor(N) to say WLOG N is torsion-free and proceed from there. For an example as to why Tor(N) is not always a summand, consider the two-element group acting on Z+Z/2 by g(x,y)=(x,x+y).

Comment: @PeterMcNamara : I wasn't suggesting to make the decomposition $G$-equivariant, but to make the projection $G$-equivariant, which is exactly what you're doing by considering $N/Tor(N)$ (I completely agree that you can't make the decomposition into $G$-submodules, that's what my parenthesis was about : otherwise you could find a map $M\to N$, which is not always the case)

Answer (score 2):

From some of the answers to my comment, it seems that it wasn't very clear, so let me make it clearer. The idea is the one I said : by decomposing $N= Tor(N)\oplus \mathbb{Z}^r$, although this decomposition need not be $G$-equivariant, the projection $N\to \mathbb{Z}^r$ can be made $G$-equivariant, and then by picking the right iso $\mathbb{Q}\otimes N\to \mathbb{Q}\otimes M$ we can find a map $\mathbb{Z}^r\to M$ that induces the iso.

Here are the details : any element of $G$ sends $Tor(N)$ to $Tor(N)$ because they are isomorphisms, therefore it induces a map $N/Tor(N)\to N/Tor(N)$ (its inverse is also an element of $G$ and so induces a map too, so clearly we actually get a $G$-module structure on $N/Tor(N)$). This $G$-structure on $N$ is such that the projection map $N\to N/Tor(N)$ (i) induces an isomorphism when tensored with $\mathbb{Q}$, (ii) is $G$-linear.

Now the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups tells us that $N/Tor(N) = \mathbb{Z}^r$, and $M$ is free, and $N\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $M\otimes \mathbb{Q}$, therefore $M=\mathbb{Z}^r$.

Now pick an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}\otimes N = \mathbb{Q}^r \to \mathbb{Q}\otimes M = \mathbb{Q}^r$. Multiply it by a sufficiently large integer $n$ so that $f(e_i) \in \mathbb{Z}^r$ for all $i$, where $(e_i)$ is the standard basis. Then $f$ restricts to a map $\mathbb{Z}^r \to \mathbb{Z}^r$, which induces an iso when tensored with $\mathbb{Q}$, and which is $G$-equivariant if you see it as a map $N/Tor(N)\to M$.

Composing this with $N\to N/Tor(N)$ yields the desired map.

Note how we see here that we can't always get a map $M\to N$ : there is no $G$-map $N/Tor(N) \to N$ in general